# Pushing item into a nested collection in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I am using the Rails gem acts_as_commentable_with_threading.  It works great.

I am also using AngularJS for the frontend.  I have a controller that returns the following JSON for the comments to be rendered:

```
[
   {
      "comment":{
         "id":1,
         "commentable_id":1,
         "commentable_type":"Post",
         "title":null,
         "body":"This is a very cool comment!",
         "subject":null,
         "user_id":5,
         "parent_id":null,
         "lft":1,
         "rgt":4,
         "created_at":"2016-12-16 03:50:24",
         "updated_at":"2016-12-16 03:51:24"
      },
      "children":[
         {
            "comment":{
               "id":2,
               "commentable_id":1,
               "commentable_type":"Post",
               "title":null,
               "body":"I definitely think this is cool too.",
               "subject":null,
               "user_id":7,
               "parent_id":null,
               "lft":2,
               "rgt":3,
               "created_at":"2016-12-16 03:51:06",
               "updated_at":"2016-12-16 03:51:24"
            },
            "children":[

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

If someone chooses to reply to the comment with the ID of 2 meaning the newly created comment would be inserted into the `children` array of said comment.  Is there a method of doing this with angular?  Or would I basically write my own recursive function that loops through each comment and its children until I find the comment object with the same ID and push the new comment into the children array?

The reason for this is I am sending the single comment over websockets to other users on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a map being a flat version of your comments nested array. You will need to recursively loop the comments array and add all elements to the map (once, before rendering comments).

For example:

```
function addCommentsToMap(comments, commentsMap ) {
    comments.forEach(function(comment) {
        commentsMap[comment.id] = comment;
        addCommentsToMap(comment.children, commentsMap );
    });
}

var commentsMap = {};
addCommentsToMap(comments, commentsMap);
```

Having such a map makes it possible to insert comments with only one operation. When a new comment comes you can simply put it:

```
commentsMap[parentCommentId ].children.push(newComment);
```

After that, the newComment will appear on your recursive array, as it consists of the same objects as the map.

Comment: Ah awesome!  I didn't even think of this. Angular. Eh. Thanks a lot.